# Form action not going to correct method in php

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, action

I'm trying to submit my form. My form was called by this function:

```
    function controller1()
    {
    $code =  $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data['content'] = $code;               
            $this->load->view(FRONTEND_DEFAULT, $data); 
            }
```

But when I submit my form, it goes back to the controller1 method, but I want it to go to another form. My form is:

```
<form id="form1" action="controller2" method="POST">  
<input type="text" name="textbox">    
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

I want it to go to `controller2` but it goes to `controller1` :

```
http://my.website.com/controller1/controller2
```

How do I prevent it from going back to `controller1`?

**EDIT:** I am using codeigniter as my framework.

Comment: *why...* why are you calling your 'controllers' `controller1` & `controller2` ?? Be descriptive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form Actions in Codeigniter gets added to the existing URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653025/form-actions-in-codeigniter-gets-added-to-the-existing-url). Also, try using the [Form Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify either a relative or absolute url

see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

i.e. action="example.htm" or action="http://www.example.com/example.htm"

Your action="controller2" is likely failing to resolve and going back to the page that output the form though I would've thought it would give an error if it couldn't resolve that action correctly

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using CodeIgniter, why not just read their manual? It shows you how to quickly and easily put together a form:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#theform

Here is a copy & paste for a form to be properly pointed to your controller:

```
<?php echo form_open('controller/method'); ?>
```

Details on the *[form helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)*